# How to fill vertices that have been traced with color

Tags: vertices

I already know how to trace a background image. I just want to know how to fill the vertices with a color of my choice. I have looked around, and even tried selecting vertices and assigning a material color, but that doesn't work. There is not enough info on the internet on blender. Please help an ambitious kid.

Comment: What is rendering? Because vertices do not display, it is the *faces* you see. You want to be assigning materials to the faces, not the vertices.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you have been creating points connected by edges, but have not created any faces.

Select the points (vertices) you want to connect and press <kbd>F</kbd> (to create a face). You can then assign a material to it and have that material be of any color of your choosing.

As a matter of precaution try not to create faces connected to more than 4 vertices.

Vertices and edges are not visible when rendered and cannot have materials, but faces can.

Comment: Thanks dude. I really appreciate the help. I been trying to figure this out for a week now

Comment: Don't post "thanks" as a comment. Instead upvote the question, and if it solved your problem consider upvoting it